# How do I check if the reader's input is between 500 and 1000? I am not sure if I'm on the right track

Tags: java

I am supposed to ask the reader to input a number and then check if it's between 500 and 1000, so i can add up the digits.  But i don't know how to check if the number is between the interval.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddNumbers {
  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //Prompt user to enter number
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 500 and 1000:");
      String number;
    number=input.nextLine();

    //Get digits from number
    char numberDigit1 = number.charAt(0);
    char numberDigit2 = number.charAt(1);
    char numberDigit3 = number.charAt(2);

    //initialize variable
    String constant=500;
    String constant2=1000;

while (number.CompareTo(constant)){
  System.out.println("The sum of the digits is: " + ((number.charAt(0) +      (number.charAt(1) + (number.charAt(2))))));
                                                                          }
while (number.CompareTo(constant)){
  if (number<=0)
  System.out.println("****ERROR: THE NUMBER MUST BE BETWEEN 500 AND     1000****");
}

while (number.CompareTo(constant2)){
  if (number>=0)
    System.out.println("****ERROR: THE NUMBER MUST BE BETWEEN 500 AND 1000****");
}


    input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Read about conditional statement like `if` `else`. Its as simple as `if(500<=number && number <=1000)`

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I think you meant to put `500 >= number`.

Comment: `0 - 9` in ASCII map to `48 - 57` in decimal. Therefore your attempt to sum each `char` will not produce desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This will not compile

```
String constant=500;
String constant2=1000;
```

But why are you even using `Strings`?

```
int constant=500;
int constant2=1000;

number=input.nextLine();

int realInt = Integer.parseInt (number);

if (realInt >= constant && realInt <= constant2) {
    // you still have `number` so

   int result = 0;
   for (char ch : number.toCharArray ())
   {
       result += Integer.valueOf ("" + ch);
   }
   System.out.println (result);
}
```

Comment: OP's using `Strings` and `chars` to sum each digit in the entered number. Which OP is doing wrong, but that's what it looks like OP is doing.

Comment: I have to use strings so I can add up the digits, but since I'm using strings it won't allow me to do an action such as (500>=number)

Comment: Updated so that you can `sum`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading input as a string and converting it into an int, we can directly validate integer input e.g:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    int input;
    if(!scanner.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Input must be a number.");
    }else{
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        if(input < 500 || input > 1000){
              System.out.println("****ERROR: THE NUMBER MUST BE BETWEEN 500 AND     1000****");
        }
    }
```